# IBM Mainframe scrape in dot net core application

Tags: javascript, .net-core, client-server, mainframe, cics

I have a requirement where I need to scrape the IBM mainframe(HOD) screen in a Dot net core web application with React JS as the front end.

I am using IBM UtilityBridge which is a COM component. I am able to make it work in my local machine on a console application but the problem we have is to make it work in a Prod environment. I want to explore option where the server in dot net or python and a HOD session in the client machine interact with each other if that is possible at all?

Comment: I can't quite understand the final question.  Can you rephrase?

Comment: I want to explore options where a server code in dot net or python can interact with a Mainframe session opened in a client machine

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building the wheel from scratch, you should utilize the Host on Demand API. A 3270 telnet session has multiple layers of data in the data stream. Trying to rewrite that in .NET or Python is unreasonable (and expensive). Get a license of IBM HOD if you're company does not already have it (this is part of the IBM HOD, PCOMM 3270 emulator package).

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSS9FA_14.0.0/com.ibm.hod.doc/doc/SessionManager/SessionManagerAPI.html